# Usage of predict on regression model

Tags: matlab, inference, prediction-interval

I'm trying to understand how to calculate the prediction interval (PI) from a regression model.
I want to calculate the PI of specific values not observed in the dataset.

I saw that predict can do it with a linear model.

What I did in Matlab is

```
rm=fitlm(X,Y)
[ypred,yci] = predict(rm, [10 20])
```

Based on my data, this gives me

```
ypred =

   49.0679


yci =

   47.7748   50.3610
```

What I'm trying to do is "manually" calculate the PI with

```
dati_PI[1;10;20]
rm.Coefficients{:,1}'*dati_PI+[1,-1]'*(tinv(0.95/2,rm.DFE)*rm.RMSE*sqrt(1+(dati_PI'*([ones(n,1) rm.Variables{:,[1 2]}]'*[ones(n,1) rm.Variables{:,[1 2]}])^-1)*dati_PI))
```

that is derived from the formula

[image]

which gives me a different PI

```
   48.8856
   49.2502
```

As far as I read on the docs, the `predict` command by default uses alpha=0.05 so it is not the level of the interval explaining the difference.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that you are looking at a [tag:prediction-interval], not a [tag:confidence-interval]. The two are unfortunately often confused, but [there is a fundamental difference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/prediction-interval/info).

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thanks. I'll take care of that in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A the end I understand the difference.

`predict` function gives the Confidence Interval on the Mean with teh formula

[image]